# Raspbmc: music playback keeps cutting out, but video playback is fine

Tags: raspbmc, audio-playback

I've been using Raspbmc for a few months now and for the first while everything was running smoothly, but in the past month or so I've been noticing a problem where when I'm in the middle of playing some music, after a few minutes the songs will start cutting out, i.e. they will keep playing and seemingly pausing every few seconds. It's obviously quite annoying and it's impossible to enjoy the music once this starts happening, but I'm stumped as to why it only happens for music playback but not video playback.

In the past, I noticed that this (cutting out) would happen only when I was doing things like rsyncing a large number of files, or downloading a lot of files at once, and once I was finished with the tasks the music playback would go back to being flawless. But now I'm noticing it even when playing music is all that I'm doing. Can someone tell me where I should start to attempt to debug this?

If someone could also tell me why it's only happening for music but not for video, that would be fantastic too.

Comment: The music is over HDMI?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy It's connected to a TV over HDMI and played through the TV speakers, yes.

Comment: What format are the music files?

Comment: Mostly mp3. There are some aac, m4a, wma, and flac files in there too, but I would say that it's 95% mp3.